# text flows to next page overlap with header in prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

**I'm using Prawn.rb to generate pdf and stuck in one problem:**

I have a header on every page, when I user ***span***, text in the ***span*** will flow to the next page and overlap with the header, but if I user ***bounding_box***, text in it will start at the cursor where the ***bounding_box*** start with when the text flows to the next page.

Here is my header:

```
repeat(:all) do
      transparent(0.5) do
        bounding_box [bounds.left, bounds.top], :width  => 
        bounds.width do
             image "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo-of-
             nextcode.png", height: 20
             move_down 2
             stroke_horizontal_rule
        end
        bounding_box [bounds.left, bounds.bottom + 50], :width  => bounds.width do
          text_box 'PRIVATE & CONFIDENTIAL', align: :center, valign: :bottom, size: 10
        end
      end
```

And here's the long text:

```
span(bounds.width) do
      object.actions.each_with_index do |a, i|
      text "#{i + 1}. Description: #{a.message}"
      text_box "Expected Completion Date: #{a.expected_completion_time&.strftime('%F')}", at: [0, cursor]
      move_down 15
      text_box "Actual Completion Date: #{a.actual_completion_time&.strftime('%F')}", at: [0, cursor]
      move_down 20
      end
end
```

My question is: how to avoid the overlapping with header if use ***span*** and how to avoid the large blank row between header and text if use ***bounding_box*** ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to put your header into `canvas`

```
    repeat(:all) do
       canvas do 
         transparent(0.5) do
         bounding_box [bounds.left, bounds.top], :width  => 
         bounds.width do
            image "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo-of-
            nextcode.png", height: 20
           move_down 2
           stroke_horizontal_rule
         end
         bounding_box [bounds.left, bounds.bottom + 50], :width  => bounds.width do
         text_box 'PRIVATE & CONFIDENTIAL', align: :center, valign: :bottom, size: 10
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem as you and a nice workaround that I came up with is you can change the page top margin when you first instantiate Prawn and add the `at:` option onto your `image` so that it would be positioned at the top of the pdf page.

I.e. If the current margin is [35,35,35,35] and your image is 20 in height then you can set the top margin to 55. If the current page height is 722, then set the `at:` option as so:

```
def instantiate
  super(margin: [55, 35, 35, 35])
  repeat(:all) do
    image "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo-of-
    nextcode.png", height: 20, at: [0, 722]
  end
end
```